# onClick event to open another component outside of a parent element in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, jsx

I have a single page react app with two components so far. `MenuScreen` and `HomeScreen`. The current onClick event within MenuScreen shows HomeScreen as a child of MenuScreen when the SpeechBubble icon is clicked. How can I trigger the onClick to show the HomeScreen Component outside of the MenuScreen? This screenshot shows what I'm trying to do.

[image]

**MenuScreen.js**

```
import store from '../libs/store.js';
var jsforce = require('jsforce');

class menuScreen extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        const data = store.getState();

        this.state = {
            username: '',
            messages: data.messages,
            records: [],
            showModal: false,
            showChat: []  //initially blank array
        }
    }

    handleSearch(e) {
        this.setState({
            username: e.target.value
        })
    }

    handleChange(evt) {
        this.setState({
            username: evt.target.value.substr(0, 100)
        });

    }

    onClick(i, e) { 
        e.preventDefault();

        let showChat = this.state.showChat.slice();
        showChat[i] = !showChat[i];  //use that index to change the specific value
        this.setState({ showChat })
    }

    onLinkClicked() {

        var conn = new jsforce.Connection({
            serverUrl: 'https://cs63.salesforce.com',
            accessToken: sessionStorage.getItem('token')
        })

        var parent = this.state.username
        //console.log(this.state.username)
        conn.sobject("Contact").find({
                LastName: {
                    $like: parent
                }
            }, 'Id, Name, Phone, Account.Name'

        ).sort('-CreatedDate Name').
        limit(5).skip(10).execute((err, records) => { //use arrow function
            if (err) {
                return console.error(err);
            }
            this.setState({
                records: records,
            })
        })

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='menubox' id='menubox'>

                <div className="boxbox">
                    <input className="search" type="text" placeholder="Contact Last Name" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.username} />
                    <input className="submit" type="submit" onClick={this.onLinkClicked.bind(this)} value="GO" /></div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        /*use the index also in map*/
                        {this.state.records.map((record, i) => (
                            <div className="info-block block-info clearfix">
                                <div className="square-box pull-left">
                                    <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-user glyphicon-lg"></span>
                                </div>
                                <h5>{record.Name}</h5>
                                <h4>{record.Phone}</h4>
                                <p>{record.Account.Name}</p>

                                   <a onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, i)}>
                                    <img src="./img/speechbubble.png" className="textIcon" />
                                     {this.state.showChat[i] && < HomeScreen / >}
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        )
    }

}

export default menuScreen;
```

**mainApp.js**

```
class MainApp extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();

        const data = store.getState();

        this.state = {
            username: '',
            messages: data.messages,
            records: [],
            records: data.records,
            showChat:data.showChat

        };



    }


    render(){
    return (
      <div>
      <MenuScreen />
      </div> 

        );
    }
}


export default MainApp;
```

**HomeScreen.js**

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();

        //Redux podaci za "hardcoding"
        const data = store.getState();

        this.state = {
            username: '',
            messages: data.messages,
            records: [],
            records: data.records,
            showChat:data.showChat

        };




}






    render(){
    return (
        <div>
          <h2>HELLO</h2>
          <p>Cras facilisis urna ornare ex volutpat, et
          convallis erat elementum. Ut aliquam, ipsum vitae
          gravida suscipit, metus dui bibendum est, eget rhoncus nibh
          metus nec massa. Maecenas hendrerit laoreet augue
          nec molestie. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
          dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>

          <p>Duis a turpis sed lacus dapibus elementum sed eu lectus.</p>
        </div>
      );
    }

}

export default HomeScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be for there to be a higher level component, like `Page`, that wraps both your menu and the content section. `Page` would then determine which content is shown.

You also mentioned you are working with a single page app. This may be a great time to use React Router. Using React Router, clicking on the Home Screen link would change the url, which would render the component mapped in Router, like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path='/home' component={HomeScreen} />
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

You may want to google around for examples using React Router with a sidebar, like [this one](https://css-tricks.com/learning-react-router/).